# Rails 3.1.0 rc 4 - Segfaults

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Can you help with that?

https://gist.github.com/1040635

GemFile, default plus:

gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'devise'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'simple_form'

The log speaks for itself.

Comment: Could you update/close your question with your findings you mentioned in the gist?

Comment: I didn't post that comment (gist). cowboyd - maintainer of therubyracer - did. Just posted the answer below. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Aaron:

@tenderlove: @eduardordm likely [this is the problem](http://blog.thefrontside.net/2011/06/13/therubyracer-isnt-threadsafe-yet/) (make sure to click the "[workaround](https://gist.github.com/1011718)" link for a fix)

Thing is, therubyracer (pre 0.9.1) is not thread safe.

Solution:

```
gem 'therubyracer', "~> 0.9.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines from your stack trace make me think you are validating the uniqueness of something in your Posts model:

```
METHOD /Users/eduardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31rc4/gems/activemodel-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:81
METHOD /Users/eduardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31rc4/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:176
CLASS  /Users/eduardo/Intermeta/smsy/app/models/post.rb:3
TOP    /Users/eduardo/Intermeta/smsy/app/models/post.rb:1
```

Can you post your Post model class?

Comment: rails 3.1 stacktraces sometimes come all the way from hell. therubyracer version was the problem. posted the answer below, thanks :D